# Some pages works only after refresh

Tags: wordpress

I have a WordPress website and a problem. Some pages (randomly) can only be seen after refresh. There's no pattern. The same with dashboard. Does somebody had such issue? What can be the problem? There're no errors in the console.

Comment: Sounds like a caching issue. Do you have WP Total Cache, Super Cache or something similar installed? Try purging its cache, disable it and check if the problem still is present.

Comment: @TomM Thanks. That is what I thought. There was W3 Total Cache but I had removed it.

Comment: look in your wp-content directory. Total Cache is pretty persistent. Maybe some cache-files or the .htaccess in wp-content/cache weren't deleted when you removed it.

Comment: @TomM I have removed it properly.

Comment: do you have any other plugins installed?

Comment: @TomM A lot of them.

Comment: It happens the same sometimes when I update the page or a post.

Comment: Ok. Almost fixed as it is plugin conflict. After deactivating all the plugins WordPress is working normally. Must find out which plugin now.

Answer (score 0):

are you behind proxy, if yes then allow then change setting to allow y

Comment: Hello, what does it mean?